# Custom backend implementation with ensembles

Tags: ios, objective-c, ensembles

I was wondering if there's someone who tried to use [Ensembles](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles) and integrate it with custom API (own back-end) ?

On repo specs it says: The framework can be readily extended to support any service capable of moving files between devices, including custom servers. Not sure what custom servers means...